# Describing the inequalities $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 8$ and $z \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ with spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

I have two inequalities:

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 8$ and $z \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

These make up a body $K$ in 3D space. I would like to represent this body $K$ using spherical coordinates, but I'm unsure on how to do it.

Basically I want it on the form:

$x = r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$

$y = r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$

$z = r\cos(\theta)$

And determine how $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ change.

I can set the inequalities to equal eachother, and get the projection that they make on the $xy$  plane, which is $x^2+y^2 \le4$ but I'm not sure if that is useful for this problem.

Comment: Try to express the inequalities in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$, the first inequality translates into $0\le r\le\sqrt8$.

For the second one observe that $x^2+y^2=r^2\sin^2\theta$, so that the inequality becomes $r\cos\theta\ge r\sin\theta$, or equivalently $\tan\theta\le1$, that is $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$.

The solid is a cone with vertex at the origin and aperture $\pi/4$.

**Note**: the usual notation has $\theta$ and $\phi$ interchanged.

Comment: How did you find that $x^2+y^2=r^2sin^2\theta$? Also shouldn't the solid be a cone with the small part of the sphere on the top? As this: http://i.imgur.com/pGOaHVB.png

Comment: Ignore my first question, I have found that $x^2+y^2=r^2sin^2\theta$ is true